# How to get the preview image of Stream Webpart to show in page created via graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online

I am following this Microsoft doc on how to use Graph API to create pages. I used it to create a page with a Stream Webpart. The issue is that the Webpart on the page doesn't show a preview even though the video was attached.

[image: error page]

I tried following this doc. I was able to create a JSON but for the page but couldn't get the correct preview URL.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/sitepage-create?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http